# RSS feed service/API that returns full article text for Python project

Tags: python, api, rss

I'm looking for an RSS feed service or API that automatically returns the full text content for feed articles.
Since primary focus of the project is natural language processing, I would like to use something that gives me the full text for articles and not just a summary and also deals with pagination. I'm not sure if this is possible for arbitrary feeds, but if there's a service that does this for common (e.g. New York Times, Washington Post, Wall Street Journal) feeds, that would be enough.

If there's no good free service or API that offers this, I would also consider paid services.

I already looked at [feedparser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) and it seems that it does not give you full text content.

Answer (score -1):

https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/

Demo:
https://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a service/API that does the scraping for me. Since this is not the main focus of the project, I don't want to roll my own feed reader at this stage.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, then.

Comment: Thanks! If there's nothing for Python I'll give it a try.